# Hiding Database of one user from another user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two user named as USER1 and USER2 in mysql.
I want to provide previliges to each user in such a way that they can not see and access of each-others databases but they should have full access of their own databases. 
   **For example-** if USER1 creates db1 and USER2 creates db2 then USER1 should not be able to see and access db2 and vice-versa for USER2. How can is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to revoke all privileges from these users

`revoke all privileges, grant options from user1, user2`

Than you should grant privileges for these users

`grant all privileges on database_name.* to 'user1'@'localhost';`

`grant all privileges on database_name.* to 'user2'@'localhost';`